# Java-fx ant application not runnig netbeans

Tags: java, javafx

[image: output]

So I have this application that was working and suddenly stopped working.
NetBeans gives no error but gets stuck on (run-single) running...
And the app never launches
The main class is below
I also have a controller class, a model class and the view FXML file

```java
package taxes;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
/**
 *
 * @author Arsene
 */
public class Taxes extends Application {
 
    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
        Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("FXMLDocument.fxml"));
        Scene scene = new Scene(root);
        stage.setTitle("Gestion Des Taxes");
        stage.setScene(scene);
    }

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

I don't seem to get what is wrong. Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: It looks like the wrong java version appears in your FXML file. [edit] your question and post the FXML file (as text and not as an image)

Comment: Okay let me do it. But the code always ran like that with that Warning

Comment: That's a warning. It probably has no effect on your program running. Catch that exception instead of throwing it. That will probably tell you what is wrong.